# Ovh cron error with phpmailer

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer, ovh

I've made a php script backing up my database in some file.sql then mailing that file to a backup mail with phpmailer.

**The script works fine** both on localhost and on my ovh server when I run it manually.

But when it's being run on **task scheduler, it doesn't do anything.**

I finally found in ovh logs the error :

```
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] ## OVH ## START - 2015-08-27 00:04:03.481779 executing: /usr/local/bin/php.ORIG.4 -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini /homez.716/my_info_name/www/php/backup/backup.php 
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] Content-type: text/html
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] 
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] <br />
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in <b>/my_server_path_to_php_mailer/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] 
[2015-08-27 00:04:03] ## OVH ## END - 2015-08-27 00:04:03.573742 exitcode: 255
```

I don't know how to fix this. I read it could be some php version issues but I'm using default php version (app.engine.version=5.4 in .ovhconfig) and last phpmailer code downloaded on github.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mailer parse error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752889/php-mailer-parse-error)

Comment: I saw that post, seems like his script doesnt work at all. Mine works, except throu ovh task planer. + I'm not using php4 :(

Comment: X-Powered-By: **PHP/4.4.9**

Comment: Here is my phpinfos on my ovh server : http://www.noelshack.com/2015-35-1440773428-azeaezeaz.png I'm using PHP Version 5.4.38. How come the logs show PHP 4.4 ? What's that version ?

Comment: Found what the problem was, ovh cron can use a different version of PHP than the one used on the server. 
I was indeed using PHP 5.4 but the cron task was done with PHP 4.0. It can be changed on the task properties. Thanks for your anwsers, lead me to the answer.

Comment: If you need, I link a guide from ovh website in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Hostings use different php version for cronjobs. Maybe you have to set it manually.

Read this http://guides.ovh.com/MutualiseCron